# Feather/buffer raster boundary during mosaic in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, buffer, nodata

I have two rasters I would like to merge and also fill in no data cells along the boundary between the two rasters to create a smooth transition. Some of the cells along the boundary are no data cells, and they are not filled when I try the Mosaic raster layers tool by SAGA. I have tried both the feathering and blend boundary method for the "overlapping areas", but I suppose this only applies to the areas that actually overlap. Therefore, I'd like to feather/buffer my raster boundary to create data for the existing nodata cells for cells which are an x distance away from cells with data, similarly to how the built-in buffer tool for vectors works.

Is this possible with any built in tools in QGIS?

I've attached an image of my output from the Mosaic raster layers tool.

[image: Unwanted no data cells along merged raster boundary]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. The tool I wanted was Fill nodata by GDAL.